# Complex android activity animation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I need to create a complex animation but in my mind I cannot figure out how to do it. I'm thinking in showing frame-by-frame animation with png's or showing a GIF animation, but im not sure that those approaches will be correct. Can anyone tell me how can I create an animation like this:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B60PF7TVN_9HfnlNUHc0TnRJZ0ZWY3UzWVc3dmllazFWYl8tVDB0ZENfTTRUajZraUZINDQ&usp=sharing

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I follow the link, it says I don't have permission to view the animation.

Comment: @Kmeixner oh, i forgot, here is a new link
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B60PF7TVN_9HfnlNUHc0TnRJZ0ZWY3UzWVc3dmllazFWYl8tVDB0ZENfTTRUajZraUZINDQ&usp=sharing

Comment: I think i saw that animation in Android Arsenal --- https://android-arsenal.com/free -- check the animations there you may get lucky.

Comment: @Tasos I've just checked them all, but no luck.. :( Thanks for your answer though..

Comment: whats hard in implementing it using `ValueAnimator`?

Comment: @pskink do you have some example to share?

Comment: no, i have just an idea to share... ;-)

Comment: check activities section too, they contain animations too